# Who does the "Crown prosecutor of Russia" refer to?

Tags: law, russian-federation, judiciary

In an email sent from Rob Goldstone to Donald Trump Jr. that was [released by Trump Jr. on Twitter](https://twitter.com/DonaldJTrumpJr/status/884789418455953413), it was mentioned in one email that the "Crown prosecutor of Russia" met with Aras Agalarov.

> The Crown prosecutor of Russia met with his father Aras this morning ...

I am curious **what is a Crown Prosecutor** and **who holds that position currently**?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Basically, [this article by The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2017/07/russian-crown-prosecutor/533295/) explains that Rob Goldstone likely mixed up the titles. Crown Prosecutor is a title commonly used in Commonwealth realms, that refers to a prosecutor that works for the Crown, i.e. a federal prosecutor or [a state prosecutor in the context of a state](http://www.businessinsider.com/what-is-crown-prosecutor-of-russia-donald-trump-jr-emails-2017-7/?r=US&IR=T).

However, there is no such position in Russia, so he's likely referring to the [Prosecutor General of Russia](https://eng.genproc.gov.ru/management/genprokuror/), a position currently held by Yury Chaika. In the US, the analogue would be the Attorney-General.

Comment: Your use of 'federal' might get confusing, since the term Crown prosecutor is also used in (e.g.) England and Wales, which is a division of a unitary state, and thus has no federation to prosecute for. Although I realise calling them a state prosecutor is equally confusing in reverse.

Comment: @origimbo Makes sense, thanks! I've updated the answer to include both.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that Goldstone is British, so translating a title into an equivalent British title makes sense.

Comment: So, it's as if I -- an American -- had referred to the "Attorney General of Russia".

Comment: @Deolater: Isn't that a bit like translating "minister" into "secretary"? Which would be weird given I don't see that kind of "translation" in American journalism... is it just me?

Comment: @Mehrdad It is similar. I don't see it happen in American journalism, but Goldstone isn't a journalist, so he doesn't have a manual of style or whatever to guide him. I might make a similar 'translation' when talking informally about a foreign title, especially if it's from another language. I have seen the 'translation' of US titles go the other way, with Congress being called a parliament, the Secretary of State being called a Foreign Minister (this one by the BBC), and other similar things (states being called provinces).

Comment: @Deolater: Ah, interesting. Yeah. Then there are the non-translations that don't make sense to me, like keeping "Shah" as-is, instead of translating it into "king". Kind of weird when they choose to translate and when they don't.

Comment: @Deolater I don't think it makes any sense at all: Russia doesn't have a Crown, and a term such as "state prosecutor" or "federal prosecutor" would have avoided a lot of confusion. It's like translating Putin's position as "King". (And it's very surprising that you saw the BBC refer to the US Secretary of State as the Foreign Minister. Are you sure it wasn't in the context of a sentence such as "The foreign ministers of France, Germany, Canada and the USA", where it would be awkward to list all the separate titles, and the lower-case letters indicate a purely descriptive term?)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I wasn't meaning to defend the usage as somehow valid. It's an informal email between a publicist and a businessman, and was (quite obviously) never intended to be published. The writer of the email wasn't trying to avoid confusing us. I presume, with no evidence, that the intended recipient of the email was not confused by it.

Answer (score -2):

The term "Crown Prosecutor of Russia" is synonymous with "Attorney General of the United States".  This is the most important information in the email because it indicates that the source providing the information to Donald Trump Jr. is at the highest level of the Russian Government.

Comment: It may be intended to convey equivalent meaning but i's certainly not synonymous.

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE. Please keep in mind that we try to keep our personal opinions on this website to a minimum and try to only answer the question which was asked. I removed a part of your answer which wasn't answering the question.